# There was a problem with my game project C# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There was a problem with my game project C# code.

This is code for monster movements.

```
8 public class enemyMove : MonoBehaviour 
9 {
10   Rigidbody2D rigid; 
11   Animator anim; 
12   public int nextMove; 
13   SpriteRenderer spriter;
14   public float monsterSpeed;
15
16   public Transform target; // 타겟 플레이어
17   private play_game instance;
18   private melee mel;
19
20   public int Hp;
21
22   public GameObject gm;
23
24   void Awake()
25   {
26       rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
27       anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
28       spriter = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
29
30       instance = FindObjectOfType<play_game>();
31       mel = FindObjectOfType<melee>();
32  
33       Invoke("Think", 4);
34   }

    ..skip..

169    public void endDmg()
170    { 
171        gameObject.layer = 7; #Enemy layer
172        spriter.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
173    }
174    public void setDmg()
175    {
176        spriter.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.4f);
177
178        int dirc;
179        if  (target != null)
180            dirc = transform.position.x - target.position.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
181        else
182            dirc = transform.position.x - instance.transform.position.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
183
184        rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(dirc, 1) * 7, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
185        gameObject.layer = 10; #EnemyDamaged layer
186
187        Invoke("endDmg", 1f);
188    }
```

And this is the code for collider 2d when attacking a monster.

```
8 public class melee : MonoBehaviour 
9 { 
10     private enemyMove enemy;
11 
12     static public melee instance;
13 
14     public Transform self;
15
16     void Awake()
17     {
18         enemy = FindObjectOfType<enemyMove>();
19         self = GetComponent<Transform>();
20     }
21
22     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
23     {
24         if (collision.gameObject.layer == 7 || collision.gameObject.layer == 9)
25         {
26             if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
27                 enemy.setDmg();
28         }
29     }
30 }
```

This project has a portal that moves maps, which moves Scene.

If you go to the next map and come back and attack the monster, you get the following error.

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'SpriteRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

> UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer.set_color (UnityEngine.Color value) (at <8744f615ca0c450898baad3219003b45>:0)

> enemyMove.setDmg () (at Assets/monster/enemyMove.cs:176)

> melee.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/player/melee.cs:27)

Can you solve this problem?

I tried to solve it, but I couldn't.

Comment: What did you try. The error is quite specific and tells you what to do.

Comment: Are you using `DontDestroyOnLoad` for the object that owns this script? If you have references to things that are destroyed when the script loads you'll need to acquire them again. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to access a SpriteRenderer component that has been destroyed or unloaded from the scene. This can happen when you change scenes and the references to the objects in the previous scene are lost1.

One possible solution is to use DontDestroyOnLoad on your enemy objects so that they persist across scenes.